# Rails stripping quotes around html attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We've recently upgraded our Rails app from 3.2 to 4.1, and now it seems Rails is removing the quotes around html attribute values, leading to stuff like `<meta name=name />`.

I've looked around and I know now that the quotes aren't necessary, but it seems that some crawlers will miss certain attributes if they aren't in quotes. Is there a way to make Rails stop stripping these quotes out?

#### EDIT:

For example, the following code in a helper

```
content_for :meta do
  "<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex\" />".html_safe
end
```

results in `<meta name=robots content=noindex />`

and `<div class="class_name">` in a view results in `<div class=class_name>`

BUT, `<div class="multiple classes">` results in `<div class="multiple clases">`

Comment: Can you post your view code for more context?

Comment: Are you talking about the behavior of the tag helpers?

Comment: Have you tried something like `<meta name="<%= name %>">`?

Comment: did you try  '<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />'.html_safe